# Raspberry Pi FTDI D2XX

Tags: ftdi, d2xx

FTDI's samples archive libftd2xx-arm-v6-hf-1.3.6.tgz includes an example of Events. Events are implemented with the usage of pthread and FT_SetEventNotification function. The problem which I encountered is, that application during waiting for an event (FT_EVENT_RXCHAR) on Raspberry Pi 2 takes about 20% of CPU time (seen with top application).

When I debugged events sample, I noticed that it creates three threads (looks like: main thread, ftdi library thread, and pthread).

My question is, if it is normal behaviour to use 20% of CPU?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal behaviour, as FTDI driver is constanly polling the data.